# Alternativa mais leve e estável ao Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Preciso fazer um projeto de Android, mas não quero usar Android Studio pois ele é muito lento e cheio de bugs no meu computador. Que IDE ou framework alternativo eu poderia usar?

Um requisito básico do projeto é ser em Java.

Comment: Amigo, seu computador está com problemas. O Android Studio é bastante estável e leve. Por exemplo, muito mais leve que o Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se seu projeto tem que ser feito em Java, você não tem escolha. Em teoria, você poderia fazer no Eclipse, mas *começar* um projeto Android no Eclipse hoje é um suicídio de manutenção, já que o desenvolvimento Android nele já não é mais suportado oficialmente (o Eclipse já foi a IDE oficial para Android, através do plugin ADT).

Se pudesse ser feito usando HTML5/Javascript/CSS, você teria várias opções, como o [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/intel-xdk) e o [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn771552.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (usando Xamarin).

Acho estranho o Android Studio ter muitos bugs na sua máquina. Ele é estável o suficiente para ser usado por milhões de pessoas todos os dias. Quanto a ele ser pesado, provavelmente é falta de memória no seu computador. Trabalhar nele com menos de 6 GB de RAM é pedir para sofrer, especialmente se seu SO é o Windows ou se você pretende usar emulador.

Comment: Pois é, tenho 4gb apenas, mas obrigado mesmo assim, já vi que não tenho escape, vai ser com sofrimento mesmo kk,

Comment: 6GB num mac ou linux dá no mesmo "sofrimento"...

Comment: @DanielOmine No Mac eu não sei, mas no Ubuntu 16.10, 6 GB dá para trabalhar, sim. O sofrimento vai vir na hora de mandar rodar em emulador, daí recomendo 8 GB (é o que eu tenho e recomendo). Se você vai mandar rodar só em aparelhos físicos, 6 GB no Ubuntu sempre deu pra mim. Isso, claro, usando Firefox. Imagino que usando Chrome a coisa deve ficar mais complicada.

Comment: voce pode tambem digitar tudo no braço e compilar usando o ant e keytool e jarsign para prepar o apk ara publicação, dai qualquer editor de texto é bem mais leve do que qualquer uma dessas IDE, riririri

Comment: O calcanhar de aquiles dele é o emulador. A IDE é rápida e prática, acredito que haja soluções aderentes de emuladores, como o Geny Motion e o Andy Android Emulator, por ai vai, a unica coisa que muda é o suporte as versões do android, o que no oficial do android studio não tem tanto problema, ou seja, é um "toma lá, dá cá".